# How to clip an image to a rect in minecraft coder pack (mcp)

Tags: java, minecraft, lwjgl

I am coding a custom minecraft client and I am drawing an image in game using

```
mc.getTextureManager().bindTexture(new ResourceLocation("Garbg/Circle.png"));
Gui.drawModalRectWithCustomSizedTexture(30, 100, 0, 0, 25, 25, 25 ,25);
```

Does anybody know how to clip that circle to a rectangle on the screen? I am pretty new to java and minecraft coding. I am not using a mod api like forge.

Comment: @Rabbid76 minecraft uses opengl

Comment: But your question is not about OpenGL. It is abut mcp

Comment: But is there a way to clip an image to a rect in opengl? I can still render stuff manually without the tools built in to minecraft

Comment: OpenGL is a low level API.

Comment: Also I am working with tools that incorporate opengl

Comment: Then I will tag it with lwjgl

Comment: I'm pretty sure those parameters `30, 100, 0, 0, 25, 25, 25 ,25` are telling it which part of the image to draw, and where to draw it.

Comment: 30 is the x position, 100 is the y position 0, 0 is preventing tiling and 25,25,25,25 is the size